# Excel VBA - Refresh selected queries / connections

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

**Situation**

I have 5 `Workbook connections` set up that query data from an MS Access database, and I have given them the names `qry_1`, `qry_2`, ... , `qry_5`

I have a selection of these query names listed in a table called `qry_Table` on a worksheet:

```
Query Name
----------
qry_1
qry_4
qry_5
```

and I can loop through the table (using `.listObjects`) to get each query name as a `string`

**Question**

I can loop through all the queries in the workbook and refresh them all, but I can't seem to work out how to select and refresh only those queries listed in the table, namely `qry_1`, `qry_4` and `qry_5`.

I would like to be able to `set` the query object so that I can define the `.Connection` string too.

Is this possible?

**Notes**

The code here shows how I get each row in the column `Query Name` of the table `qry_Table`

```
    dim wksControl As worksheet
    dim objList As ListObject

    set wksControl = worksheets("Control")    'the worksheet that contains 'qry_Table'
    Set objList = wksControl.ListObjects("qry_Table")

    With objList.ListColumns("Query Name").DataBodyRange

        For i = 1 To .Rows.count              
            str = .Rows(i)    'query name to refresh
            '***Required: Define the qry to refresh
            Set qry = .QueryTable(str)  '<~~ this code fails
            'code to .Refresh  BackgroundQuery:=False

        Next i
    End With
```

And to refresh all the queries in the workbook I can use

```
    'code for generic query connections
    For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
        If objList.SourceType = xlSrcQuery Then  'only refresh if it's the right query type

            'ensure it's using the right connection/database as specified on the Control sheet
            strConnection = "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & Range("dbFilePath") & _
                Range("dbName") & ";DefaultDir=" & Range("dbFilePath") & _
                    ";DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;"

            With objList.QueryTable
                .Connection = strConnection
                .BackgroundQuery = False
                .Refresh
            End With
            count = count + 1
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `activeworkbook.connections(str).refresh`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, and yes it worked for refreshing individual queries. However, what I didn't make explicitly clear in my question was that I want to be able to set the `.Connection` property of the query too. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Your part 2 would need to be: `With wks.Listobjects(str).QueryTable`

Comment: @Rory That's the one, thanks. If you want to make it an answer I'll give it a tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to the `ListObject` by name, rather than the connection, and then access its `Querytable` property:

```
With wks.Listobjects(str).QueryTable
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `str = .Rows(i)` you are assigning whole row's range to str, replacing the line with `str = .Cells(i,1).Value` should work as it will return value in first column of the `i` row.

Comment: However, that still doesn't let me `set` a query object